# Performance concerns regarding ALTER TABLE ADD COLUMN

Tags: mysql, sql, performance

I have a big MySQL InnoDB table having 5 million rows. I need to add a column to the table which will have a default `int` value.

What is the best way to do it? The normal alter table command appears to take a lot of time.  Is there any better way to do it?  Basically I want to know if there is any faster way or efficient way of doing it.

And if the table has foreign key references, is there any way other than alter table to do this?

Any help appreciated.

Comment: It's likely taking a lot of time because there are data changes being made.  Did you set a default value?

Comment: yeah.. i set a default value.  the column is integer with default value 1.

Comment: That'll do it.  Adding a column is a metadata operation, and is usually quite quick, but by setting a default it became a data operation that needs to be performed on each row of the table.  For a large table, that will take some time.

Answer (score 1):

I would not say this is a better way, but ...  You could create a separate table for the new data and set it up as foreign key relationship to the existing table.  That would be "fast", but if the data really belongs in the main table and every (or most) existing records will have a value, then you should just alter the table and add it.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose the table looked like this:

```
CREATE TABLE mytable
(
    id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    name VARCHAR(25),
    PRIMARY KEY (id),
    KEY name (name)
);
```

and you want to add an age column with

```
ALTER TABLE mytable ADD COLUMN age INT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0;
```

You could perform the `ALTER TABLE` in stages as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE mytablenew LIKE mytable;
ALTER TABLE mytablenew ADD COLUMN age INT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0;
INSERT INTO mytablenew SELECT id,name FROM mytable;
ALTER TABLE mytable RENAME mytableold;
ALTER TABLE mytablenew RENAME mytable;
DROP TABLE mytableold;
```

If `mytable` uses the MyISAM Storage Engine and has nonunique indexes, add two more lines

```
CREATE TABLE mytablenew LIKE mytable;
ALTER TABLE mytablenew ADD COLUMN address VARCHAR(50);
ALTER TABLE mytablenew DISABLE KEYS;
INSERT INTO mytablenew SELECT id,name FROM mytable;
ALTER TABLE mytable RENAME mytableold;
ALTER TABLE mytablenew RENAME mytable;
DROP TABLE mytableold;
ALTER TABLE mytable ENABLE KEYS;
```

This will let you see how many seconds each stage takes. From here, you can decide whether or not a straightforward `ALTER TABLE` is better.

This technique gets a little gory if there are foreign key references.

Your steps would be

- `SET UNIQUE_CHECKS = 0;`
- `SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;`
- Drop the foreign key references in `mytable`.
- Perform the `ALTER TABLE` in Stages
- Create the foreign key references in `mytable`.
- `SET UNIQUE_CHECKS = 1;`
- `SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1;`

Give it a Try !!!

Comment: I will try this and let you know if there are any improvements.  I have made a few changes in my questions.  I want to know if there is any way to do this if there are foreign key references?